# If turtles see everything, and nothing seen can see, does it follow that non-turtles exist?

Tags: logic, existence, deduction

Consider the following argument:

Turtles see everything. Seeing is asymmetric (for the sake of argument). Therefore, something is not a turtle.

I have problems symbolizing these statements.

My attempt:

**Predicates:**

Tx: x is a turtle

Sxy: x sees y

**Premises:**

1) (∃xTx) Λ ∀x∀y(Tx → Sxy)

2) ∀x∀y (Sxy → ¬Syx)

Using this set-up I cannot deduce the conclusion, which is ∃x¬Tx.

I feel like my set-up is wrong. I think I should be able to complete the proof after correctly symbolizing the statements. Please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Isn't ths a take on Rissell's paradox?

Comment: I think in the second premise, you're taking the converse instead of the contrapositive. Asymmetric doesn't mean that the reverse is always untrue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, your premises are inconsistent: your second premise implies that turtles do not see other turtles, or themselves, yet, according to the first premise, they see everything. So, taking y=x, we can deduce both ∀xSxx and ∀x¬Sxx. After that you can deduce whatever you want directly using the [law of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), contradiction implies anything.

If you fix this, e.g. by specifying that turtles see everything *but* turtles, your desired conclusion will not be deducible. This is because in the standard predicate calculus the universal quantifier does not have what is called [existential import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_fallacy). In other words, ∀yP(y) → ∃yP(y) is generally false. So ∀x∀y(Tx → Sxy) may hold even if there is no y for x to see. It is interpreted conditionally: *if* there was a non-turtle y *then* any turtle x would see it. Hence, your modified premises will hold even in a world of turtles only. Just as you specified that your world is not empty, with ∃xTx, you'll have to specify *explicitly* that it is not devoid of non-turtles, with ∃x¬Tx. Or, you can add existential import as a separate axiom, and apply it to P(y)=∀x¬Syx. Then ∃y∀x¬Syx, together with the first premise, will give you ∃y¬Ty.

Comment: I think the premises are consistent, but imply that there are no turtles

Comment: @rtpax The first premise specifies that there are turtles.

Comment: missed that, you are correct